# In playwright, how to set the Chrome browser to acept all cookies and don't block fingerprinting?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, playwright, fingerprinting

Chromium accept and show all cookies and don't block fingerprinting, but now i need to do the same in Chrome but i don't know he args to accept all cookies and don't block fingerprinting, all i have is:

```
browser = playwright.chrome.launch(
        channel='chrome',
        headless=False
        ignore_https_errors=True,
        args=[
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--no-zygote',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--window-position=0,0',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors-skip-list',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--mute-audio',
            '--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess'
        ]
    )
```

How do i set Chrome to accept all cookies and don't block fingerprinting ?